# How to fix Static method 'list' requires that 'Transaction' conform to 'Model' error in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, graphql

I'm trying to use a grapghQL API to query a list of data and return an array of that data. From that array, I will pick one random value to use. The code looks as follows:

```
`func queryLyrics() { 
var lyricArray : [Lyric] = [] 
Task { 
   do { 
     let result = try await Amplify.API.query(request: .list(Transaction.self))
            switch result {
            case .success(let lyricsData):
                print("Successfully retrieved list of Lyrics")

                // convert an array of LyricData to an array of Lyric class instances
                //an array of LyricData to get one Lyric class instance
for n in lyricsData {
                    let lyric1 = Lyric.init(from: n)
                    MainActor.run {
                        lyricArray.append(lyric1)
                    }
                }
                let goodLyric = lyricArray.randomElement()

            case .failure(let error):
                print("Can not retrieve result : error  \(error.errorDescription)")
            }
        } catch {
            print("Can not retrieve Notes : error \(error)")
        }
    }
}.`
```

However, the .list function provides the error: Static method 'list(_:where:includes:limit:)' requires that 'Transaction' conform to 'Model'. Im wondering why this is? and how can I fix this?

I'm trying to use a grapghQL API to query a list of data and return an array of that data. From that array, I will pick one random value to use. Is there a better way to query for the data with the API? Or a different function besides list that will work better?